# anorm logback.xml "without play"

Tags: scala, anorm

Is that possible to configure `anorm`, when it used **without** play framework to log (using `logback.xml` f.e.) `sql` queries it sends to db?

So far I try to use these deps:

```
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "6.0.4",
"org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc"       % "2.4.2",
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-logback" % "2.5.3",
"ch.qos.logback"  %  "logback-core"   % "1.1.7",
"ch.qos.logback"  %  "logback-classic"   % "1.1.7",
"org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.21",

"janino" % "janino" % "2.5.10"
```

and that conf:

```
<configuration>

    <!--<conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.libs.logback.ColoredLevel" />-->

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>logs/application.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date [%level] from %logger in %thread - %message%n%xException</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{10}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="logger.org.jdbcdslog.StatementLogger"  level="DEBUG" />
   <logger name="anorm.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement"  level="DEBUG" />

   <logger name="anorm" level="TRACE" />
   <logger name="anorm.SQL" level="TRACE" />


    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

I see some information in the logs but not sql queries...

**Q: how to let Anorm print sql queries?**

*Right now I do not have any error in the log/deps*

In play we may use: `db.default.logStatements=true`

but how to go without play?

Comment: This error isn't raised by Anorm, which is not using any logging framework

Comment: now I resolved deps. so no errors. but now slq in the log either

Comment: As said previously, Anorm doesn't log any query/update

Comment: For debug purpose (not logging): http://acolyte.eu.org/scala/#debug-utility